# How best to join tables, which have different lengths on the same column values which exist in both tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I think my problem is pretty simple, and in SQL this would be trivial. I have two tables

```
TableOne = {{a, x1}, {b, x2}, {c, x3}};
TableTwo = {{a, y1}, {c, y2} , {a, y3}, {a, y4}, {b, y5}, {c,y6}, {c, y7}}
```

I want to abe able to join these two tables where the values of column 1 in both tables match such that:

```
DesiredResult =  {{a, x1, a, y1}, {c, x3 , c, y2} , {a, x1, a, y3}, {a, x1, a, y4}, {b, x2, b, y5}, {c, x3, c, y6}, {c, x3, c, y7}}
```

I've tried with both `Select[]` statements inside a `Table[]` structure and also looked into `JoinAcross[]` but haven't been able to acheive the desire effect. In SQL it would be simple, something like:

```
SELECT Col1.Table1, Col2.Table1, Col1.Table2, Col2.Table2,  FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON Col1.Table1  = Col1.Table2
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should stay away from associations because your keys aren't unique. Maybe just go over all tuples of elements and pick those that match your criterion:

```
Reap[Outer[If[#1[[1]] == #2[[1]], Sow@Join@##] &, TableOne, TableTwo, 1]][[2, 1]]

(*    {{a, x1, a, y1}, {a, x1, a, y3}, {a, x1, a, y4}, {b, x2, b, y5}, {c, x3, c, y2},
       {c, x3, c, y6}, {c, x3, c, y7}}    *)
```

Alternatively, construct a list of all tuples and then select: (this may use more memory if the lists are large)

```
Flatten /@ Select[Tuples[{TableOne, TableTwo}], #[[1, 1]] == #[[2, 1]] &]

(*    {{a, x1, a, y1}, {a, x1, a, y3}, {a, x1, a, y4}, {b, x2, b, y5}, {c, x3, c, y2},
       {c, x3, c, y6}, {c, x3, c, y7}}    *)
```

Comment: That'll do it, thanks again Roman.

Answer (score 6):

```
assocOne = AssociationThread[First /@ #, #] & @ TableOne;

f = Join[assocOne[First @ #], #]&;

Map[f] @ TableTwo
```

> {{a, x1, a, y1}, {c, x3, c, y2}, {a, x1, a, y3}, {a, x1, a, y4}, {b, 
>       x2, b, y5}, {c, x3, c, y6}, {c, x3, c, y7}}

Comment: Also a very nice solution, +1!

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[Table[Join[n, #] & /@ Cases[TableTwo, {n[[1]], _}], {n, TableOne}], 1]

  (* {{a, x1, a, y1}, {a, x1, a, y3}, {a, x1, a, y4}, {b, x2, b, y5}, {c, 
  x3, c, y2}, {c, x3, c, y6}, {c, x3, c, y7}} *)
```

Comment: So far you are winning on the compactness of the code!

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
Join[Extract[TableOne, #], TableTwo, 2] &[
  Lookup[PositionIndex[TableOne[[All, 1]]], TableTwo[[All, 1]]]]
```